# How to I convert this column to row format ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can use Pivot but my table here has only 2 columns so I don't know how to go about with it. A class has maximum of 5 UserIDs so I want to have a ClassID and associated 5 user names.

```
UserID  ClassID
RK980   5
LO567   5
YY667   5
RT223   5
LT987   3
```

What I need is :

```
ClassID User1 User2 User3 User4 User5
5         RK980 LO567 YY667 RT223 NULL
3         LT987 NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  I would then tend to go for conditional aggregation rather than `pivot`:

```
select classid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then userid end) as user1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then userid end) as user2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then userid end) as user3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then userid end) as user4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then userid end) as user5
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by classid order by userid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by classid;
```

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator. This is the error I get

Comment: @vap0991 in the sample code you weren't using unique identifiers. You'll need to convert them to `nvarchar` first: `max(case when seqnum = 1 then convert(nvarchar(36),userid) end) .....`

Comment: Yes but like the row_number doesn't generate 1 to 5 it gives a 1 to all the userid that are from the same company.

Comment: Umm thats exactly how my dataset looks except the values are different but the datatypes are same so it should not matter

Comment: @Lamak  I figured for it to have a sequence you need to partition by classid and not by userid like the code above says, its working now like I wanted it to. that was the only difference

Comment: @vap0991 yeah, you are right, didn't notice that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pivot` with `row_number`

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (UserID  VARCHAR(10),  ClassID INT)
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES
('RK980',   5 ),
('LO567',   5 ),
('YY667',   5 ),
('RT223',   5 ),
('LT987',   3 )

SELECT ClassID, [1] User1, [2] User2, [3] User3, [4] User4, [5] User5  FROM 
    (SELECT * ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClassID ORDER BY UserID ) AS RN
        FROM @MyTable ) SRC
    PIVOT(MAX(UserID) FOR RN IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) PVT
```

Result:

```
ClassID     User1      User2      User3      User4      User5
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
3           LT987      NULL       NULL       NULL       NULL
5           LO567      RK980      RT223      YY667      NULL
```